# Create Custom Hashtable

Tags: java, generics, hashtable

I need to create a Custom Hashtable extends java.lang.Hashtable and i need to override the get method to achieve the following behavior :

1. if the key == null, it will return a new object of the type V
2. if the super.get(key) == null, it will also return a new object of type V.

Can anyone help me.
I try to do this but I know it's wrong.

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class CustomHashtable<K, V> extends Hashtable {
    @Override
    public synchronized V get(Object key) {
        if(key == null) return new Object();
        Object v = super.get(key);
        if(v == null){
            return new Object();
        }
    }

}
```

please see the line :

```
if(key == null) return new Object();
```

and the lines :

```
if(v == null){
    return new Object();
}
```

to know where the error occurred..

Comment: What *is* the error ? I'm guessing but can you be explicit ?

Comment: The Error is Syntax error : The Method return type is V, and i try to return an Object type... this is the error

Answer (score 10):

You'd have to store the class related to V and create a new instance. For example:

```
public class CustomHashtable<K, V> extends Hashtable {
    Class<V> clazz;

    public CustomHashtable(Class<V> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized V get(Object key) {
        if(key == null) return newValue();
        Object v = super.get(key);
        if(v == null){
            return newValue();
        }
    }

    private V newValue() {
        try {
            return clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException (e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException (e);
        }
    }
}
```

(You may want to change the exception handling of course.)

An alternative is to make the caller effectively provide a factory to create a new instance of `V`. You'd do this with an interface such as:

```
public interface Factory<T> {
    T create();
}
```

You could then store the factory in the custom hashtable, and call `create` any time you needed to.

Answer (score 3):

The primary issue here is what you are trying to achieve is fundamentally wrongheaded. Checkout the methods of your class. The majority of them will now be inconsistent with `get`. Worse, exactly how methods are implemented in terms of other public methods is not defined - such is the curse of inheritance.

Therefore, create a class that represents whatever abstraction you are trying to achieve. Have the *contain* not inherit from an appropriate map implementation.

The natural map in this case is probably not ye olde `Hashtable` but [`java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). The important method here is [`putIfAbsent`][2]. Unfortunately the API docs suck. Here is how it should be used:

```
public V getOrCreate(K key) {
    final V value = map.get(key);
    if (value != null) {
        return value;
    }
    V newValue = factory.create(key); // May discard.
    V oldValue = map.putIfAbsent(key, value);
    return oldValue==null ? newValue : oldValue;
}
```

(You can use a `Future` if you want to ensure that you never discard a value.)

To create I've assumed some kind of an abstract factory. In general methods don't have no-args public constructors that happen not to throw exceptions. Certainly avoid reflection like swine flu crossed with H5N1. Instead use an appropriate (abstraction-specific) abstract factory passed in at creation time.

```
public interface MySortOfFactory<
    T /*extends SomeEntity*/,
    A /*extends SomeInfo*/
> {
    T create(A arg);
}
```

[2]: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#putIfAbsent(K, V)

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to create a new instance? or is it sufficient to return a *default* instance?
The latter could be implemented like:

```
public class CustomHashtable<K, V> extends Hashtable<K, V> {

    /** Default instance. */
    private final V defaultValue;

    public CustomHashtable(V defaultValue) {
        this.defaultValue= defaultValue;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized V get(Object key) {
        if(key != null) {
            V val = super.get(key);
            if(val != null) {
                return val;
            }
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

(but I still prefer Jon's factory solution: more flexible and also covers the default instance solution)

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you asked, but could I ask the following please:

- Do you always want a new object when the key is null, or don't you just want to allow a null key?
- Also, do you definitely need a new instance when you can't find the key, or will the same instance do in each case where you can't find the key?
- Are you going to put the new instances into the Hashtable?
- Does it have to be a Hashtable, or could a HashMap do?

I'm just wondering if you had considered using a [LazyMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/LazyMap.html) from Apache Commons Collections?

Comment: Thanks A_M, the LazyMap idea is a good also, i don't know any thing about it before. Thank you for your Help